# NavigationBar Right Items Hides when Show inner ViewControllers

Tags: swift, xcode

I use navigation bar with tabbarcontroller. When i push one of my tabs my navigationbar right items are hiding automatically.

How i can move my items to childs controllers?

Comment: Set the `navigationItem` on the new view controller.

Comment: How? I only see back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create base view controller and inherit your children classes from base view controller then call `super.viewDidLoad()`

1- Base controller

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "LogOut", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.logoutTapped(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton
    }

    @objc func logoutTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        print("Logout clicked :) ")
    }
}
```

2- VC one

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}
```

3- VC two

```
class ViewController2: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}
```

Result

[image]